# Ether wallet stuck while syncing. Can I upgrade without syncing?

Tags: wallets, ether, synchronization, dao

My ether wallet (0.5.2) is stuck on block 2,420,853 while syncing.

Can I upgrade to 0.8.1 without syncing?

My goal is to convert my Dao tokens to ether. So I need to update my wallet.

Eeek!

Thank you!

Comment: How in the name of Ether did you get with 0.5.2 to block 2,420,853? Upgrade to 0.8.6 (at least) as soon as possible, whatever you do.

Answer (score 1):

There were two hard forks since you last updated your client. Please upgrade to Mist browser or Ethereum wallet of at least version 0.8.6 (at the time of writing).

After upgrading, you might have to reset your blockchain. But do not hesitate to upgrade first, else transactions might fail due to wrong gas costs coded into the client.