# Speeding up Syncing Mist

Tags: mist, synchronization

My Mist/Eth wallet is syncing very slow, it stays 200k blocks behind.

- I have 12-13 peers
- using the most recent version of mist.
- Internet connection is not an issue
- RAM 4GB and rest of hardware shouldn't be a problem too

I've read something about increasing cache to speed up significantly but is that possible within Mist client and if yes,  can someone guide me in this?

Thx!

Comment: Check out: [Blocks are not being downloaded](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9002/87), [Ether wallet stuck while syncing. Can I upgrade without syncing?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9279/87), [Running Wallet 0.8.6 with Parity 1.3.8 Low # peers, Low speed](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9402/87).